# Не у всех пользователей работает audio.get

Tags: аудио, vkontakte-api, auth, actionscript

Друзья, игра под ВК. Iframe приложение.

```
    public function UpdateActualMusicItem ():void
    {
        _main._api.VK.api('audio.get', {'uid':_main.viewer_id}, onReceiveUsers, onReceiveError);
    }
```

Так получаю содержание музыки пользователя. Проблема в том, что у некоторых работает. У некоторых нет. Наткнулся, что, возможно, проблема связана с правами на музыку.
Пытаюсь искать примеры по Интернету по ключевому слову scope = audio. Но таких примеров почти нет.
Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался? Как решить проблему?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ошибка есть?

Comment: Да, работает только у меня. У друзей не работает. Вот нашел много подобных тем, и пока все без ответа...
http://www.flasher.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=162830
Политик файл в порядке... Из за чего еще может быть?

Comment: Приведите код ошибки.

Comment: В том то и дело, что мы не заходим в onReceiveError. Т.е. ошибки нету. Грешу на авторизацию. Из APIConnection, может, надо дополнительно логин делать?
____
Кстати, у меня и у двоих человек работает, а еще у троих - нет. Если есть возможность посмотреть, могу предоставить необходимый доступ, в профиле ссылка на меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Случайно нашел проблему...

```
_api.VK.api('audio.get', {'uid':_main.viewer_id, 'offset':offset, 'count':MaxItemInPage}
```

Надо указывать offset. Так как люди, есть у которых в по 10к песен. Как только явно указал, всё, у всех заработало.